# Delete from whichever column has the name in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, select

I have an unassign button and I want to remove the person logged in from whichever column he is in because I have 2 columns and he may be in any of them.

**Schema:**

App

```
ID int primary key not null auto_increment
Name varchar(50) not null
Email varchar(50) not null
Person1 varchar(10)
Person2 varchar(10)
```

**Query:**

```
mysql_query("delete from App where (App.Person1 OR App.Person2) = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["user"])) . "' and App.ID = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["edit"])) . "'");
```

As you can see I have tried using `OR` but It doesn't remove the person logged in from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete statement is wrong. It must be:

```
mysql_query("delete from App where (App.Person1 '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["user"])) . "'  OR App.Person2 = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["user"])) . "') and App.ID = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["edit"])) . "'");
```

And 2 other things:

1. You should not use mysql_* functions because these are deprecated
2. You should use prepared statement.

Comment: Upvoted it... But before I accept it.. how will I do it for the assign button? I know by using the `INSERT INTO` statement but I only want to insert it into `Person1` or `Person2` if any of them are `NULL`

Comment: @User I can't get you. But I think it is a new question. So you should askk it as such.

Comment: I don't follow the logic in accepting this. It was posted after my answer, is practically identical, and also needlessly duplicates code.

Comment: @MightyPork I have writen this at the same time as you. But needed more time. And which answer will be acepted is a decision of the OP. So I do not think it is a good practice to downwote a correct answer.

Comment: @MightyPork And it is not the same answer!! There are two hints that are not in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
DELETE FROM App WHERE (App.Person1 = '...' OR App.Person2 = '...') AND App.ID = '...'
```